# Action calling recursively in my middleware when data fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, middleware, preloader

I have component App which render its children and Header component. I use  Preloader from react-loader repo which takes bool loaded and render preloader or page in depended from bool. When App componentWillMount, data fetch via actionCreators, action use redux-api-middleware, then when execute *render* in *App*, *Header* fetch data via actionCreator *boundGetPhotos* which execute recursively look *PHOTOS_GET_SUCCESS* in [console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiuS7.jpg) here i log action.type in my *fetchingMiddleware* . All actions pass from my middleware *fetchingMiddleware* look belowe. Which can be reasons of recursive behavior why it execute again and again and how i can solve it

**App**

```
 import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
 import Counterpart from 'counterpart';
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';
 import Loader from 'react-loader';
 import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
 import { getFriends, getMessages } from '../data/Data.Actions';
 import { getUsers } from '../users/Users.Actions';
 import Header from './Header';

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { boundGetFriends, boundGetMessages, boundGetUsers } = this.props;
    boundGetFriends();
    boundGetMessages();
    boundGetUsers();
  }

  render() {
    const { children, fetching } = this.props;

    return (
      <Loader loaded={!fetching.size}>
        <div>
          <Header/>
          {children}
        </div>
      </Loader>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  boundGetUsers: PropTypes.func,
  boundGetMessages: PropTypes.func,
  boundGetFriends: PropTypes.func,
  fetching: PropTypes.array
};

export default connect((store) => {
  return {
    fetching: store.fetching
  };
}, (dispatch) => {
  return {
    boundGetUsers: bindActionCreators(getUsers, dispatch),
    boundGetFriends: bindActionCreators(getMessages, dispatch),
    boundGetMessages: bindActionCreators(getFriends, dispatch)
  };
})(App);
```

**Header**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import ImmutablePropTypes from 'react-immutable-proptypes';
import { getPhotos } from '../user/User.Actions';

class Header extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { boundGetPhotos } = this.props;
    boundGetPhotos();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar fluid collapseOnSelect>
        <Navbar.Brand>
          <a href="/">MyProject</a>
        </Navbar.Brand>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

Header.propTypes = {
  boundGetPhotos: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect((store) => null, (dispatch) => {
  return {
    boundGetPhotos: bindActionCreators(getPhotos, dispatch)
  };
})(Header);
```

**FetchingMiddleware**

```
import { startFetching, endFetching } from './FetchingMiddleware.Actions';

export default store => next => action => {
  console.log(action.type);
  if (typeof action !== 'function' && action.type.search(/REQUEST/) !== -1) {
    store.dispatch(startFetching());
  }
  if (typeof action !== 'function' && action.type.search(/SUCCESS|FAILURE/) !== -1) {
    store.dispatch(endFetching());
  }

  next(action);
};
```

**FetchingMiddlewareReducers**

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';
import { END_FETCHING, START_FETCHING, RESET_FETCHING } from './FetchingMiddleware.Actions';
import createReducer from '../utils/utils';

function addFetching(state, action) {
  return state.push(true);
}

function removeFetching(state, action) {
  return state.pop();
}

function resetFetching(state, action) {
  return Immutable.List();
}

export default createReducer({
  [END_FETCHING]: removeFetching,
  [START_FETCHING]: addFetching,
  [RESET_FETCHING]: resetFetching
}, Immutable.List());
```

**FetchingMiddlewareActions**

```
export const END_FETCHING = 'END_FETCHING';
export const START_FETCHING = 'START_FETCHING';
export const RESET_FETCHING = 'RESET_FETCHING';

export function endFetching() {
  return {
    type: END_FETCHING
  };
}

export function startFetching() {
  return {
    type: START_FETCHING
  };
}

export function resetFetching() {
  return {
    type: RESET_FETCHING
  };
}
```

**getPhotos**

```
import { CALL_API } from 'redux-api-middleware';   
export const PHOTOS_GET_SUCCESS = 'PHOTOS_GET_SUCCESS';

export function getPhotos() {
  return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      endpoint: '/photos',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'include',
      types: ['REQUESTPHOTOS', PHOTOS_GET_SUCCESS, 'FAILURE']
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<Header />` component should be a pure component that knows nothing about your state container (Redux) or dispatch.

Using the approach you have here would litter your component tree with 'connect' and add awareness of Redux to all of your components. This is bad practice in terms of scalability - what if you wanted to replace Redux with another state container?.

I would recommend that all state and actions should be bound to props and passed down the tree into your components such as the `<Header />` component.

This should also resolve the issues you are having.

**App**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Counterpart from 'counterpart';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Loader from 'react-loader';
import { getMasterDataSchema, getMasterDataData } from '../masterdata/MasterData.Actions';
import { getQuestionnaireSchema } from '../questionnaireschema/QuestionnaireSchema.Actions';
import Header from './Header';

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { 
      GetMasterDataData, 
      GetMasterDataSchema, 
      GetQuestionnaireSchema
    } = this.props;   

    GetMasterDataData();
    GetMasterDataSchema();
    GetQuestionnaireSchema();
  }

  render() {
    const { children, fetching, GetPrincipal } = this.props;

    return (
      <Loader loaded={!fetching.size}>
        <div>
          <Header GetPrincipal={GetPrincipal} />
          {children}
        </div>
      </Loader>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  GetPrincipal: PropTypes.func, 
  GetQuestionnaireSchema: PropTypes.func,
  GetMasterDataSchema: PropTypes.func,
  GetMasterDataData: PropTypes.func,
  fetching: PropTypes.array
};

export default connect(({ fetching }) => ({
    fetching
}), {
  GetPrincipal,
  GetQuestionnaireSchema,
  GetMasterDataData,
  GetMasterDataSchema,
})(App);
```

**Header**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Header extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { GetPrincipal } = this.props;
    GetPrincipal();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar fluid collapseOnSelect>
        <Navbar.Brand>
          <a href="/">EMS</a>
        </Navbar.Brand>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

Header.propTypes = {
  GetPrincipal: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Comment: It can solve  with Header component, but that if in children component also occurs fetching